# PCA reducing the accuracy of my neural network and also causing to overfit

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, computer-vision, pca

I'm trying to implement a neural network for handwritten digit classification problem.

I have total 42,000 labeled image samples and 28,000 unlabeled images samples that I need to predict. Each image is 28x28 so there are total 784 pixels or features.

So first I normalize the data samples using sci-kit-learns MinMaxScaler and train my neural network. It has 9 hidden layers and 590 hidden nodes and I'm using ReLu. My score is 97.399%, so I think it is good.

After that, I thought I should use PCA in order to reduce the dimension of the data and make the training process faster.

I'm reducing the dimension of the data to 100-300.

But PCA is reducing the accuracy of the neural network and also causing to overfit.

With PCA I'm getting less than 50% accuracy.

I try to change the number of hidden layers and hidden nodes but still, the accuracy is below 50%.

**So what should I do?**

Comment: Given that you report accuracy > 97% w/o PCA, it is unclear what exactly you are asking

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to make the algorithm faster. And also sometimes PCA increases the accuracy of the neural network, so I'm trying to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It will not work because the reduced images have poor resolution(with no useful/good features for prediction).

- Though PCA does not throw away every other pixel and it only transforms the data to have important features, reducing the dimension to 100-200 features can be too low. You cannot represent a good image with that.
- You must select the number of dimensions in a way that maximum variance is retained. So in case of images, the maximum variance can be said just by visualizing the image.
- Reducing Dimensions in an image where pixels are the features, would mean downsampling the image. So if you reduce the number of features(pixels) to 100-200 from 784 features(pixels), then most of the important features might be gone, resulting in poor performance.
- Try visualizing the image after dimensionality reduction, compare it with the image with 784 pixels, you will see the difference.
- If you still want to use PCA and reduce the dimensions, you can reduce it to a level where you can visually approve the image to have a good amount of features for the algorithm to work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: PCA transformation doesnt work that way. Even if you keep the same amount of components, its not guaranteed to return a visual image.

Comment: Yes, I do know that PCA does not throw away every other pixel and it transforms the data to have important features. But still, 100-200 features are too low. You cannot represent a good image with that. You must select the number of dimensions in a way that maximum variance is retained. So in case of images, the maximum variance can be said just by visualizing the image.

Comment: Of course, it will. you can visualize the input features because the training samples are images. Please check the dataset here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer

Comment: I am not talking about visualizing the input image. I am talking about visualizing the data returned from pca.

Comment: Yes it is possible. https://www.r-bloggers.com/image-compression-with-principal-component-analysis/